# Why is the eBay FixedPriceTransaction notification going to the buyer when it is a notification for the seller only?

Tags: ebay-api

I had recenlty setup the `FixedPriceTransaction` notification for a client which would send the order related details to the client website in the event of an order on eBay. This has worked fine.

Recently the client logged into his eBay account and bought an item from another seller on eBay and for some reason beyond my understanding the website received the notification for this transaction as well.

My understanding is that the `FixedPriceTransaction` notification is only sent to the seller when some one buys an item from them on eBay so this should not be sent in the case I have mentioned above.

Can any one point out why the above is happening?

Answer (score 1):

It goes to both. You have to check whether the recipient user ID matches the seller's user ID in order to verify whether you should import that data into your selling application.